# Is it possible to load the Sqlite JSON Extension using SQL?

Tags: json, sqlite

I am writing some `Sqlite` queries and I would like to use some `JSON` functions

I have found these `JSON` functions as a Sqlite extension mentioned [here](https://sqlite.org/json1.html):

Which says:

> The json1 extension is a [loadable extension](https://sqlite.org/loadext.html)

I read about a Loadable extension and eventually get to the [SQL Load extension function](https://sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#load_extension)

> The load_extension(X,Y) function loads SQLite extensions out of the
>   shared library file named X using the entry point Y.

I have tried

```
Select sqlite3_enable_load_extension();
Select sqlite3_load_extension(json1.c, 1);

select Json_array_length(StatData) From [Diary.CallVersion];
```

But this returns nothing. So what have I done wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sqlite3_enable_load_extension()` is not an SQL function but a part of SQLite's C API.

In other words, you are allowed to load extensions only if the application in which the SQLite library is embedded has explicitly allowed this.

Comment: so if I'm writing a c# application which executes queries on sqlite I am not able to do what I am trying to do above?

Comment: You can enable extensions (or load them directly) from your C# code.